Failed to execute goal 32morg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5
I am getting this build error with maven surefire plugin while running a pom.xml file for selenium testing.
Failed to execute goal 32morg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31mException in provider[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31morg.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireExecutionException: Exception in provider

